# How do I return an ArrayList<String> from ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>.get()

Tags: java, object, arraylist, getter-setter, object-to-string

I have an ArrayList like : `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> test`

```
for(int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList temp = test.get(i);
}
```

It turns out now, that I cannot do `Arrays.deepToString(temp.toArray())` since temp is an Object and not < ArrayList< String>>.

Also, I am doing `temp1.contains(temp.get())` temp1 and temp2 are actually objects with the same values < ArrayList< String>>. They even have some common ArrayLists within them. However, due to this Object problem, this does not work.

Is there any way by which I can basically return an ArrayList or so instead of an object so that I can get the `.contains()` method to work. As I said... the ArrayList within temp has the same number of columns, some with the same values.

Please help me out.

Comment: Why don't you declare temp as an `ArrayList<String>` ?

Comment: Note: you can also use a foreach to make it clearer : `for(ArrayList<String> temp : test){ ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList temp = test.get(i);
```

should be

```
ArrayList<String> temp = test.get(i);
```

Comment: And how do I do the contains?

Comment: temp1.contains(temp.get(0)) will do it if temp1 is also a string collection

Answer (score 1):

If you parameterize the ArrayList and pass over the return type to the `toArray()` it should work fine.

```
for(int i = 0; i < test.size(); ++i){
    ArrayList<String> temp = test.get(i);
    temp.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

The `toArray()` now returns a String[]

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> test=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    test.add(list);
    ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<>();
    for(ArrayList<String> arr:test) {
        temp = arr;
    }
```

Comment: then   if(temp.toString().contains("")) use